# How do I control which Excel chart axes pair I plot a data series to?

Tags: excel, charts, axes, multiple-axes

I have three data series (x-y) I want to plot as scatter graphs in Microsoft Excel.

I want the first series to be plotted using the bottom x-axis and left y-axis.

I want the second series to be plotted using the top x-axis and the left y-axis (again).

I want the third series to be plotted using the bottom x-axis and the right y-axis.

So I need four different axes on the four sides of the chart area.  Excel seemingly can place primary and secondary horizontal and vertical axes okay but I can't seem to control which combination of these my data series are plotted to - only whether they are "primary" or "secondary" which isn't enough detail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Screenscrab of chart area with the three data series present.  The blue series is correctly plotted against bottom X and left Y but the orange and red series are plotted against the wrong y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yYzH.png)

Comment: click on the series and you can set the x-axis as the second argument, 3rd argument is y-axis.

Comment: @SolarMike Can you explain a bit more please?  I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Start by clicking on a series and looking at the formula bar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.